# RuntimeError: Error loading /content/testing.csv

Tags: python, csv, runtime-error, runtime, loading

**I'm trying to load a CSV file in Python using the `csv` module, and I'm encountering a `UnicodeDecodeError` with the following error message:**

```
from langchain.document_loaders.csv_loader import CSVLoader

loader = CSVLoader(file_path='/content/testing.csv' , 
source_column="prompt")
data = loader.load()
```

Error :
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/langchain/document_loaders/csv_loader.py in load(self)
67         try:
---> 68             with open(self.file_path, newline="", encoding=self.encoding) as csvfile:
69                 docs = self.__read_file(csvfile)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/content/testing.csv'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/langchain/document_loaders/csv_loader.py in load(self)
83                 raise RuntimeError(f"Error loading {self.file_path}") from e
84         except Exception as e:
---> 85             raise RuntimeError(f"Error loading {self.file_path}") from e
86
87         return docs

RuntimeError: Error loading /content/testing.csv

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can you send the folder structure you currently have? What file is this script running from and where is the folder you want to access?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code this is somewhat hard but here is a suggestion: let python replace invalid characters with Unicode replacement symbol when using the CSV module:

```py
import csv
with open("your_file.csv", "r", encoding="utf-8", errors="replace") as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    for row in reader:
        pass
        # Your processing logic here
```

The magic is in the `errors='replace'`

Answer (score 0):

This below snippet is how I read and extract data from CSV file:

```
import pandas as pd

# Read CSV data into a Pandas DataFrame
data = pd.read_csv('./content/testing.csv')

# Convert DataFrame to JSON format
jsonData = data.to_dict(orient='records')

# Iterate through each row in the JSON data
for row in jsonData:
    # Your custom logic here
```

Hope this helps in addition to [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77423987/21035210) by [Markus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11609332/markus-hirsim%C3%A4ki).